# how to avoid automatic hotspot login popup from the point of view of the hotspot device?

Tags: authentication, networking, hotspot

I'm in control of the http server of an IOT device that is the hotspot. This device http server offers some settings but it doesn't provide Internet connection.

When I connect from an Ubuntu PC to this device, Ubuntu pops up a "Hotspot Login" window. This is ""useful"" when you are in an airport to agree with the terms and get Internet access. Here is an example of such window found on Google:

[image]

This feature is controlled by Gnome NetworkManager. I know how I can disable it but that's not the point of my question.

[image]

My question is how can I handle the situation on the device http server to basically tells any network daemon (Linux, Windows or Mac): "there is no internet connection, don't try, don't bother your user with a login page, that doesn't make sense..."?

Is there an official rfc specification to handle hotspot auto login page?